# How to know the time at strategy.entry to set stop loss at the activation bar LOW?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am trying to write a strategy using `strategy.entry` and `strategy.exit`. I want to set the stop loss for my buy position at the LOW of the bar that activated my ENTRY. For that, I think the best way is to get the time of the entry and then use it to get the LOW of the bar at that time.
The code I wrote so far is this one:

```
start = timestamp(2018, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0)

entrada_long = elder_bulls and time > start // and (close >= high[1]*1.0015)
entrada_short = elder_bears and time > start

strategy.entry("buy", true, comment = tostring(high[0]*1.0015), stop = high[0]*1.0015,  when = entrada_long)
strategy.cancel("buy", when = not entrada_long) 

take_level = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.1
strategy.exit("exit_buy", "buy", limit = take_level, stop = low[0]*0.9985, qty_percent = 100, comment = tostring(low[0]*0.9985))
```

with the built-in variable `strategy.position.avg_price` I am able to know the price at entry and use it to calculate my take profit at `strategy.exit`, I think I need something similar to know the time at ENTRY, but I couldn't find it. The way my code is the stop loss is like a trailing stop, always moving to the next bar low, I want to fix the stop at the low of the bar that activated my strategy.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a boolean value that triggers your entry.
You could make use of the [valuewhen()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_valuewhen) function to get the `low` of your entry bar.
An example of the use of this function can be seen [here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-find-the-maximum-value-among-the-last-pivots).

Alternatively, you could save the low of the bar in a [`var`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html) variable, upon activation of your trigger.
From the [manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html):

> *The var keyword is a special modifier that instructs the compiler to create and initialize the variable only once. This behavior is very
>   useful in cases where a variable’s value must persist through the
>   iterations of a script across successive bars.*